# sum of products in stock

Tags: mysql, select, sum

i need to  show the total valvue of all the  all-in-one printers in stock from the products table
the all-in-one printers can be identified by having 'A1' in positions one and two of the product id

here is what ive tried so far

```
select sum(price) AS total_price
  from products 
  where prod_id like 'A1%'
```

here is a picture of the products table

[image: product table]

Comment: That query doesn't even come close to what you say you want to do. What is it that you haven't told us?

Comment: what do you mean yea ive edited the code   abit now

Comment: when you say total value are you saying you want to include the number on hand times the price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so if i understand you correctly you want the price per item times the number on hand all summed up if thats the case this should do the trick

```
SELECT SUM(adjusted_price)
FROM
(   SELECT price * on_hand adjusted_price
    FROM products 
    WHERE prod_id like 'A1%' 
)t
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5576a5/1)